# using popen shows WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, windows

**windows 7** python 2.7 
when I use popen to open a process：

```
from ctypes import *

dldtool = cdll.LoadLibrary(r'main.dll')





cmd = "dld_tool -c {} -r programmer.bin -f {}".format(port,file)
    print cmd
    with LOCK:
        process = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
        while process.poll() is None:
            out = process.stdout.readline()
            if out != '':
                print out
```

error occurs：

```
  process = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The main.dll is in the working directory. should I change the code in python or change the any config?

Comment: What is `dld_tool`? It needs to be in the current working directory, or in the directory listed in the PATH environment variable. You could also use the full path to `dld_tool`.

Comment: dld_tool is a dll : dldtool = cdll.LoadLibrary(r'main.dll')    this dll was in the working directory

Comment: the dll was in the working directory. how to use the full path to dld_tool?

Comment: `CreateProcess` failed to find "dld_tool.exe" in the standard search path, which includes the application directory (the directory of python.exe), *maybe* the working directory (by default, but `CreateProcess` can be configured to not search the working directory, which I recommend), the System32, System, and Windows directories, and the directories in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I do not have dld_tool.exe, I only have main.dll in the working directory. I use dldtool = cdll.LoadLibrary(r'main.dll')   to use this dll.    Could you tell me the spectific solution?

Comment: main.dll has to export an API that can be called via ctypes. Read the ctypes docs completely and look for a header file (.h) and read it completely. Specifically for Windows, look up the docs for `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` so you actually understand a bit about what ctypes is doing for you. This all takes time and effort on youe part. Stack Overflow is no substitute (or at best a *terrible* substitute) for actually learning properly from the basics.

Answer (score 1):

You should use either the `shell=True` parameter if you want to pass the entire command with arguments as one string:

```
process = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
```

or `shlex.split` to split your command line into a list (after importing `shlex`):

```
process = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE)
```

Otherwise the entire command line with arguments would be treated as one file name, and the system naturally would not be able to find it.

Comment: No, Windows uses a command-line string, and `subprocess.Popen` is no exception to this since it simply passes the command line to `CreateProcess`. You're thinking of Unix.

Comment: Thank you. I use shell=True and the previous error disappear. But new error occured:     'dld_tool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.